# Pandas - select lowest value to date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas.

I've got a dataframe where I want to group by user and then find their lowest score up until that date in the their speed column.

So I can't just use `df.groupby(['user'])['speed'].transform('min)` as this would give the min of all values not just form the current row to the first.

What can I use to get what I need?

Comment: can we get an example to reproduce? [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If you do give a [mcve] please consider making it python code that can actually construct the DF for us without us having to use `read_clipboard` or other tricks to get it working locally.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your dataset it's hard to help you directly. The problem does boil down to the following. You need to select the range of data you want to work with (so select rows for the date range and columns for the user/speed).

That would look something like `x = df.loc[["2-4-2018","2-4-2019"], ['users', 'speed']]`
From there you could do a simple `x['users'].min()` for the value or `x['users'].idxmin()` for the index of the value.
I haven't played around for a bit with Dataframes, but you're looking for how to *slice* Dataframes.